# I bought software on Steam, how come it's not in my list?

Tags: steam

I just bought some software from [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/software/), but when I click on my games list, I don't see it.

**Where do I find Steam Software that doesn't appear in my games list?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Steam software is listed under the "All Software" category in the Steam client, not the "All Games" category.**

To view it, use the dropdown menu located just to the right of the search box, and select "All Software"

[image: Steam Client Large Mode]

[image: Steam Client Small Mode]

Answer (score 0):

I've had occasions where purchased software doesn't immediately show up.  Shutting down steam and restarting should resolve the problem.